# SOAP, WSDL and WS* Questions

Tags: wcf

Just a few questions about the Title:

- Can anyone give me or provide a "need to know" information about SOAP, WSDL and WS*?
- If you want to become an expert with using WCF, do you need to know everything about SOAP, WSDL and/or WS.* or just a basic understanding would do?
- Has anyone taken the MCTS 70-503 or MCTS 70-513 exams? If so, do you know what areas that I need to focus on?
- I work in a the legal service industry, has anyone seen the use of WCF in this industry?

Thank You,

Answer (score 2):

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is protocol for exchanging data in well known interoperable format based on XML.

WSDL (Web Service Description/Definition Language) is well known XML based language for description of web service interface. It describes contract of the service independently on the platform where service was developed.

WS* is name for large set of interoperable protocols which add additional features to web services. For example WS-Security describes interoperable way to secure messages and to transport credentials in secure way. WS-Policy allows extending WSDL with description of other WS* protocols used in web service, etc.

If you want to be skilled WCF developer you basic understanding is enough. If you want to be WCF expert and want to deal with interoperability, you will need more than basic understanding.

I took the first one. It covers exactly what is desribed [here](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-503#tab2).

If your industry uses Web services or if they plan to use them than you need some API to easily consume them or expose new ones - WCF is exactly that API.

Comment: I didn't prepared directly for the exam. I learned WCF because I needed it in my projects. I read Learning WCF, Essential WCF, Inside WCF and plenty of articles + I watched some web cast series. Then I took the exam. My "preparation" took about 6 months.